# Python: how to update list with zero values?

Tags: python, list, updating

I am new to python and would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.
I have a list of values as following:

```
('1', '3', '4')
('43', '3', '2')
('49', '3', '3')
('59', '3', '4')
('62', '3', '3')
('63', '3', '2')
```

and so on..
first column is for user id. This list is in ascending order of user id's.
There are missing users in between consecutive rows. I would like to fill these missing values with consecutive numbers (userid) and zeros for other columns. e.g.-

```
('1', '3', '4')
('2', '0', '0')
('3', '0', '0')
('4', '0', '0')

.
.
('47', '0', '0')
('48', '0', '0')
('49', '3', '3')
('50', '0', '0')
.

.
('59', '3', '4')
.
.
('62', '3', '3')
('63', '3', '2')
```

and so on...
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary of your tuples with the ids as keys and tuples as values then use a list comprehension to create your desire list of tuples :

```
>>> z=next(zip(*tup)) # in python 2.X use itertools.izip
>>> d={i[0]:i for i in tup}
>>> min_v,max_v=int(min(z)),int(max(z))

>>> [d.get(str(i),(str(i),'0','0'))for i in range(min_v,max_v)]
[('1', '3', '4'), ('2', '0', '0'), ('3', '0', '0'), ('4', '0', '0'), ('5', '0', '0'), ('6', '0', '0'), ('7', '0', '0'), ('8', '0', '0'), ('9', '0', '0'), ('10', '0', '0'), ('11', '0', '0'), ('12', '0', '0'), ('13', '0', '0'), ('14', '0', '0'), ('15', '0', '0'), ('16', '0', '0'), ('17', '0', '0'), ('18', '0', '0'), ('19', '0', '0'), ('20', '0', '0'), ('21', '0', '0'), ('22', '0', '0'), ('23', '0', '0'), ('24', '0', '0'), ('25', '0', '0'), ('26', '0', '0'), ('27', '0', '0'), ('28', '0', '0'), ('29', '0', '0'), ('30', '0', '0'), ('31', '0', '0'), ('32', '0', '0'), ('33', '0', '0'), ('34', '0', '0'), ('35', '0', '0'), ('36', '0', '0'), ('37', '0', '0'), ('38', '0', '0'), ('39', '0', '0'), ('40', '0', '0'), ('41', '0', '0'), ('42', '0', '0'), ('43', '3', '2'), ('44', '0', '0'), ('45', '0', '0'), ('46', '0', '0'), ('47', '0', '0'), ('48', '0', '0'), ('49', '3', '3'), ('50', '0', '0'), ('51', '0', '0'), ('52', '0', '0'), ('53', '0', '0'), ('54', '0', '0'), ('55', '0', '0'), ('56', '0', '0'), ('57', '0', '0'), ('58', '0', '0'), ('59', '3', '4'), ('60', '0', '0'), ('61', '0', '0'), ('62', '3', '3')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check how this works for me. I got what I wanted from @JuniorCompressor answer below. But I think I will try out your answer as well to learn more about python. Cheers!!